# Cannot Resize DIV to anything smaller than maximum width

Tags: css, html

Quick CSS Question. I cannot seem to figure out a very simple CSS/HTML problem. Here's a JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/BmM6t/

Basically, these two divs are not resizing to anything less than 100% width:

```html
<div id="main_pic" class="main_div">
       THIS IS WHERE THE MAIN PIC WILL GO.
    </div>
    <div id="signin" class="main_div">
       SIGN IN TO THE SITE!
       <form>
           <label for="name">EMAIL/USERNAME:</label>
           <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
           <label for="email">PASSWORD:</label>
           <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
           <br />
           <input type="submit" value="Let's Play!">
       </form>
    </div>
```

You'll see that the two divs with class main_div actually take up the entire width of the screen for some reason (you can see that if you inspect the element) even though their widths are clearly written. When you try to change the width of one of the main_div's it changes the width but if you inspect the element, it just changes the width of the object and adds padding around it to make sure it still takes up the entire width of the screen.

I'm sure it's some little error I've made but I can't find it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how `div`s work, they are block level elements. If you don't want them to take up the entire with of its container element you can `float` it or make it `inline-block`

Comment: I guess my question is that I'm trying to do a simple div right next to do a div with the main_divs. They first are showing up full width (even if I try to resize them) and then if I try to add float:left to .main_div in the CSS, it just centers the top one and doesn't float them next to each other. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @MxmastaMills the reason why the top div is where it is, is because you did not clear the floats on you unordered list elements, see http://jsfiddle.net/BmM6t/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use a `overflow: hidden;` to the `.main_div` so that you can see that it is resizing but not hiding the contents.